# Login script doesn't work - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

This login script doesn't seem to work. I checked if it gets past the if statement, and it does. What else can be the problem?

the script that handles the login:

```
<?php
    include("config.php");

    $myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
    $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
    $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM " .$members. " WHERE BINARY `username`= '".$myusername."' and BINARY `password`= '".$mypassword."'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

    $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

    if($count==1){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $mypassword;
        $_SESSION['privileges'] = $row['privileges'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
        header("location:index.php");
    }
?>
```

The script that checks if the user logged in on `index.php`:

```
<?
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        header("location:login.php");
    }       
?>
```

Comment: did you forget `session_start();` in login handling file?

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: where should I add it in the code? If i place it right before the header, it still doesn't work.

Comment: add exit after your header function call.

Comment: The log in methodology you're using is not terribly secure, you should use a hashing scheme to store the passwords.  Also, obligatory mysql_* is deprecated, you need to use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: @Andy No errors.. It just stays on the same page. So index.php might header it back to login.php..

Comment: put `session_start();` at the top of login script

Comment: Your <?php
    include("config.php"); should be: <?php session_start();
    include("config.php");

Comment: put session_start(); at start of the page. And $members is defined in config.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Improve your code like this

login-exec.php

```
    <?php
//Start Session
session_start();
//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//Sanitize the POST values
$myusername = clean($_POST['myusername']);
$mypassword = clean($_POST['mypassword']);


//Create query
$qry="SELECT * FROM " .$members. " WHERE `username`='".$myusername."' AND `password`='".$mypassword."'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        //Login Successful
        session_regenerate_id();
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['member_id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['firstname'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['lastname'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_EMAIL'] = $member['email'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_USER_NAME'] = $member['username'];
        session_write_close();
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
    }else {
        //Login failed
        header("location: login-failed.php");
        exit();
    }
}else {
    die("Query failed");
}

?>
```

And keep your index.php into this

```
  <?php session_start(); ?>
  <?php 
require_once('safe.php');
 ?>
```

Create a php page input this code for check User

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) == '')) {
    header("location: access-denied.php");
    exit();
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `session_start();` must be at the very top of the page. Also, I don't see `$members` defined anywhere. Try this.

```
<?php
session_start();
include("config.php");

$myusername = $_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword = $_POST['mypassword']; 

$username = stripslashes($myusername);
$password = stripslashes($mypassword);
$esc_username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$esc_password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE BINARY `username`= '".$esc_username."' and BINARY `password`= '".$esc_password."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count == 1) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $mypassword;
        $_SESSION['privileges'] = $row['privileges'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
    }

    header("location:index.php");
}
?>
```